# Manage few UIViewControllers in parent view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have `UIViewController` that contain another two `UIViewControllers` as properties.

MenuViewController contains:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) TeamsViewController *teamsViewController; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) ResultsViewController *resultsViewController;
```

The MenuViewController contains table view and when user tap on the cell "show teams" I need to initialize teamsViewController and show teamsViewController view. The same thing when user press on the cell "show results" but in this case I need to show resultsViewController view.

So, I usually do this is in one way initialize controllers when cell is pressed and call addSubview method that will add controllers view. But I think it is not good solution am I right?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (_teamsViewController) _teamsViewController = nil;
    _teamsViewController = [TeamsViewController new]
    [self.view addSubView:_teamsViewController];

}
```

Is the method above ok?

There is my hierarchy of view each of them managed by its own controller. So the white you managed by MenuViewController and the gray view managed by ResultViewController and blue view managed by TeamsViewController.

As I said before when I tap on appropriate cell in menu view controller I need to show teams or results. But each of this view has another view controller. Or maybe I confused about view controller paradigm? Maybe TeamsViewController should be a TeamsView and ResultsViewController should be ResultsView ? So both view controllers has the table as well that managed in their controllers. So i don't think it has to be a UIView instead of UIViewController.

[image]

Comment: It's probably easier to use a uinavigationcontroller as a base class for MenuViewController and push the other view controllers onto the navigation stack. That will give you built in 'back' functionality as well.

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose but in this case I will need to add uinaviagtioncontroller view on the main view controller view right?

Comment: it can be different devices, but the main thing that the table view is located on the top site and at the bottom i have something like container view that I achieve by adding view controller view.

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose I like the idea about navigation so I can add one view and then just push another view controllers

Comment: when I add navigationcontroller view as a suview to my view something bad with my frame  I use this code and then I can see whole view[_containerNavigationController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(247, 64, 10000, 10000)]; if i use 700 for height the view I push is cutting off but its view size 700 x 700. have you faced with the same issue

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander Instead of adding the navigation view as a subview I would change the base MenuViewController to inherit from UINavigationViewController. That will give you all the built in support that comes with a navigation view. If you'd like me to post this in an answer I can.

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose for example I have menu controller that have table but in the place with CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 300) I need to have a view that will be managed by another controller. you know what I mean? if you can please add the answer. I will add images what I mean

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose please check the sources https://bitbucket.org/matrosovDev/ios-manage-few-view-controllers I have implement what you suggest but with additional setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to set this up as a UINavigationController. UINavigationController inherits from UIViewController so you aren't losing any functionality this way. You could then set it up like this:

```
//MenuViewController.h
@interface MenuViewController : UINavigationController
   @property (nonatomic, strong) TeamsViewController *teamsViewController; 
   @property (nonatomic, strong) ResultsViewController *resultsViewController;
   //Insert other properties and methods....

@end
```

and in the method called when someone clicks on a cell, you would simply do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.teamsViewController) {
       self.teamsViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nibName" bundle:nil];
    }
    [self pushViewController:self.teamsViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Now, you have two view controllers, so you have to tell your method above which one to push onto the stack. If the rows are fixed, you can simply decide which one to show based on `indexPath` but if it's more dynamic (i.e. tableview is created from a database) then you'll need to have some more complex logic code here.

Without making too many assumptions, but to give you some general guidance, when you create a cell you would generally set some sort of flag on it to indicate what type it is. This can be done with an NS_ENUM or with a simple BOOL if you only have two states (I prefer to use ENUMs whenever possible as they are much more descriptive). You would then check for the existence of that flag in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, pushing the corresponding view onto the navigation stack. Something like this (this is not literal code, but shown just to give you an idea:

```
// This code assumes in the method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
// you have set the tag property to '1' if a TeamsViewController is
// needed or '2' if a ResultsViewController is needed when that cell
// is pressed.

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        self.teamsViewController = self.teamsViewController ? self.teamsViewController : [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TeamsViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.resultsViewController = self.resultsViewController ? self.resultsViewController : [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResultsViewController" bundle:nil];
        switch ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] tag]) {
           case 1:
              [self pushViewController:self.teamsViewController animated:YES];
              break;
           case 2:
              [self pushViewController:self.resultsViewController animated:YES];
              break;
           default:
              break;
        }
    }
```

You would still need to do your initialization in your teams or results view controller to show the view but this should steer you in the general direction.

Comment: please check the sources it is what I am looking for https://bitbucket.org/matrosovDev/ios-manage-few-view-controllers can you comment on it?

Comment: I checked out your code. Try to set your view controller to inherit from a UINavigationController in UIViewController.m You don't typically put a navigation controller in a subview position, it should be the root controller and should be in charge.

Comment: It'll likely work. I've just never used it that way. Just test it well to make sure it doesn't break and you should be fine. Good luck! Upvotes are always welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Storyboards and making sure to have a "Storyboard ID" for each of them. That way, it becomes a bit easier to push various `UIViewController` instances, as needed. This is my typical pattern:

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard
    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"selected identifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Also, unless you need to set properties in the child view controller, there's no need to have a property reference to it. Further, this answer assumes that you're using a `UINavigationController`, with your `MenuViewController` set as the `rootViewController`. You can either set this up in IB with a Storyboard (easy and probably the preferred way), or in code like this:

```
MenuViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"" 
                                                            bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navVc = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                  initWithRootViewController:vc];
```

Comment: if you see the split view controller it is something i want to ask. so but it can be for iPhone as well so we have some component that has 2 views one main and second for splaying another view controller but each views are on the screen so user every time see both views of 2 view controllers

Comment: In that case, you'd set up multiple Storyboards; one for iPhone, one for iPad, creating the UI as appropriate for each device. You cannot make 2 `UIViewController` instances visible simultaneously on the iPhone. At least, `UIViewController` instances are intended to be full-screen;

Comment: please check the sources I have implemented what I am looking for https://bitbucket.org/matrosovDev/ios-manage-few-view-controllers. Can you comment on it?